# Find number of occurrences of a certain value in an object - Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, lodash

I have a nested object and I need to calculate the number of times the 'status' field has a value of 2 and a value of -1. This is what I have.I am open to using lodash as well.

```js
const data = {
  "file1": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file1"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": 2,
    "error": null
  },
  "file2": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file2"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": -1,
    "error": "Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact"
  },
  "file3": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file3"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": 2,
    "error": null
  },
  "file4": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file4"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": 2,
    "error": null
  },
  "file5": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file5"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": -1,
    "error": "Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact Trinity"
  },
  "file6": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file6"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "error": ""
  },
  "file7": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file7"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": -1,
    "error": "Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact Trinity"
  },
  "file8": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file8"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": 1,
    "error": ""
  },
  "file9": {
    "file": {
      "path": "file9"
    },
    "loadedBytes": 1,
    "status": -1,
    "error": "Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact Trinity"
  }
}

var countStatus = (status) => Object.values(data).reduce(function(n, i) {
  return n + (i.status === status);
}, 0);


console.log({
  countSuccess: countStatus(2),
  countFailure: countStatus(-1)
})
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same result? Please note, I am using Typescript and the addition inside the reduce method causes a type error shown [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDGAiAMwEsAbAUwEY8AuTHXfY8muhhvAByQAsXDTKeergC+AGmH4SIBHDJwAQgE8oZCCwoS2eaEgCu62gCYt7MgCdzIcyzB6SJeuPr9yRltm1MyHybk48fN7uks7a0rLyyqqGMJqSOshQBiwAtPHaFlY2tHgAqmBkAB4cZMCqcDBZ1jAgwMB65vIwqTAc5AgQZDBQ5kowCADmCERgAHQwAJIEVZY1peYQRNAQYm0dXTCgYMjlQqKmrmQAzL5eAmds+FxQvLnep6Gm-hFyiipqGs-4usmxJglqjkYHYHE5Dt4ACyXfzeGHsG53RgCaFPBKvKIfWIZdi-FLGb54IG2eyOA4ubwAVnhR3h-kRQQE1LR4Rkb2in1oOP8eNi6UJxNyBWKpXKzSBtXqjWarXaZE63V6-SGI3GUxmEoWSxWazlCq24F2sAAKuZRkQoEp9jAwsjyAA2Glw2ieK4BW6Mh3W8msyLvGJfBK8wOZObAvDW21HADsTouLr810C9wEsZZ7Ax-s5cUJwdo-MBYb4wpKZQqs2ykoaTUqso2ir6A2Gowm0wr8ws2qgq3W8s22yNMFN5stkYhAgAHHHmAmrkmPSnyFP0y82ZiA1zc0l8TnC9k+GOKQIAJzTnyzt0MxdkU8rqRrrPYrf6Pnc-CC-Al0XliV1asy3t9SVJtVVbDUwzaTtlm7XV6wNHYEHKIczTAC0rScLARCwLAADcEHMA09B2ABlbcIDQGAAApeVoOwAFsACMLAASjQAA+GAAHkGIAKzLMY8JIPQ1EoxBkGYsYaz0YAyEoggiPKIhwEosA1iIVjXSaZJzDAEEYAAaioogxl5NBUHQXlmIAbkwtYAAZrOwrBtggEByDGaRBko11QCIqBiOkmSIAgWhfJIsjKKMZjTDCqAADERiEppQpAPzSJfSj0mYzDsqAA). Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error given by TypeScript can be avoided by turning the boolean expression to number explicitly, using the unary plus:

```
return n + +(i.status === status);
```

For the rest your solution is fine.

Comment: Updated OP to a function which takes in a status value

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.countBy()` to get an object with the counts of all statuses, and then get the ones you want by destructuring the object ([stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-sandbox-1ttygy?file=index.ts)):

```js
const data = {"file1":{"file":{"path":"file1"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":2,"error":null},"file2":{"file":{"path":"file2"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":-1,"error":"Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact"},"file3":{"file":{"path":"file3"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":2,"error":null},"file4":{"file":{"path":"file4"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":2,"error":null},"file5":{"file":{"path":"file5"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":-1,"error":"Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact Trinity"},"file6":{"file":{"path":"file6"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":1,"error":""},"file7":{"file":{"path":"file7"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":-1,"error":"Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact Trinity"},"file8":{"file":{"path":"file8"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":1,"error":""},"file9":{"file":{"path":"file9"},"loadedBytes":1,"status":-1,"error":"Unexpected error occured - please try again. If error persists, please contact Trinity"}}

const { '2': countSuccess, '-1': countFailure } = _.countBy(data, 'status')

console.log({ countSuccess, countFailure })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```